# Computer doesn't turn on, but power LEDs and fan do

Tags: boot, bootloader

I have an Ideapad 330s with Windows/Arch dual boot. I booted Arch today and my touchpad wasn't working (it does that sometimes) so I rebooted.

However after the screen went off, the power LED stayed on. Impatiently, I held the power button until it shut down.

Then when I switched it on again, the power LED turned on, the fan could be heard spinning, and backlit keyboard flashed on as usual. However the screen didn't switch on. At all. Zero light from the screen. I even checked in a dark room.

Frustrated I tried again and again, holding different key combinations such as ESC, all the F keys, Shift, nothing changed.

I tried plugging in an external screen but it didn't even detect that it was plugged in. No signal.

I tried removing the hard drive to force it to go to BIOS (in case GRUB was for some mystical reason the culprit), but no; zero response from the screen.

I tried unplugging the fan and the battery from the motherboard (one at a time) but nothing changed after I reinserted them.

I tried booting with an external mouse plugged in, as I thought to myself that no motherboard in its right mind would prevent me from booting without a working mouse, but no surprise, nothing different happened.

I cannot come up with any more ways to disappoint myself with after raising my hopes, so if anyone has any ideas which may help me boot my computer or identify the problem, please help me out.

Edit: I unplugged the CMOS battery (while the laptop and battery were unplugged) and then plugged everything back in but unfortunately that didn't work either.

Edit: Tried removing the ram as well as the hard drive, still nothing.

Edit: Tried replacing the ram with my friend's working ram, still nothing.

Comment: Maybe reseat the CMOS battery?

Comment: @Salocor I didn't think of that, thanks! Let's see now if you've managed to raise my hopes up for nothing

Comment: Hopefully not 

Comment: When you do that, make sure the battery and power cord are unplugged.

Comment: @Salocor I unplugged the CMOS battery (while the laptop and battery were unplugged) and then plugged everything back in but unfortunately that didn't work

Comment: Darn.  Try removing the ram as well as the hard drive to see if you can get to BIOS.

Comment: @Salocor will do, tho in my limited experience when there's no ram nothing happens (not even the bios)

Comment: Time now to take it to a local repair shop. It could be the mainboard and CPU which may make it uneconomical to repair.

Comment: If the screen isn't working I would check the monitor connection inside the laptop, maybe it corroded or disconnected? I know you don't have a Mac, but lot's of Mac laptops have this problem, a shitty little monitor cable.

Comment: @zwei7 he tried an external monitor already.  Good idea though!

Comment: I just had another idea. If your computer has two ram modules, remove one of them, turn it on and if that doesn’t work try the other one.

Comment: @Salocor nah, it's only got one ;_;